# A listener inside a ViewHolder is limiting my Activity's communication meaning not allowing me to pass data from Activity1 to Activity2

Tags: android, kotlin

As I'm incrementing my app, I need to pass data from Activity1 to Acitivity2, but the way my code is setup is limiting me to do that, and in the following codes I'll point to what I think I need to change.

In the following code, in the second class which is `ListItemCellVH` view holder, has an init and inside it has a listener set to `enterScaleDetailBtn` button:

```
class ListItemCellAdpater(private val greekModeScalesList: List<ListItemTemplate>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemCellVH>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListItemCellVH {
        val layoutInf = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemCellView = layoutInf.inflate(R.layout.cell_recycler_view_layout,
            parent, false)
        return ListItemCellVH(itemCellView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListItemCellVH, position: Int) {
        val target = greekModeScalesList[position]
        holder.note.text = target.pNote
        // setting more content to fields here
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = greekModeScalesList.size
}

class ListItemCellVH(itemCellView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemCellView) {
    val note: TextView   = itemCellView.note
    // defining more variables here
    private val enterScaleDetailBtn: ImageButton = itemCellView.enter_scale_detail_btn

    companion object {
        const val MODE_NAME : String = "MODE_NAME"
        // a bit more variable here
    }

    init {
        enterScaleDetailBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(itemCellView.context, GMScaleDetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(MODE_NAME, gmName.text)
            // some mor intent here

            itemCellView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter from the above code goes to the `MainActivity`, which looks like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var listItem = ArrayList<ListItemTemplate>()
    
    // next line we instantiate the ListItemCellAdapter from the code above
    private var listItemCellAdapter = ListItemCellAdpater(listItem)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        reciclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        
        // next line here we set the instance to a reciclerViwe's adapter
        reciclerView.adapter = listItemCellAdapter
        
        // some listeners related to this Activity goes here
    }
    // some methods related to this Activity around here
}
```

**The problem:** I need to pass some data from the `MainActivity` to a `DetailActivity`.
*I know a bit about intent and how it works, but because of how I'm setting the listener inside the ViewHolder it is abfuscating my vision about it.*
So, I think, to solve the problem, I should extract the listener from the ViewHolder and define it in other place, but then I don't know where to put it, and what to do with the button the listener is set to. So this is where I need help.

And finally, here's the `DetailActivity`

```
class GMScaleDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val navbarString by lazy { resources.getString(R.string.navbar_text_gmscaledetailactivity) }
    private val greekModesNameArray by lazy { resources.getStringArray(R.array.greek_modes_name_array) }
    private var MINOR_MODES = arrayListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmscale_detail)

        val modeName = intent.getStringExtra("MODE_NAME")
        // getting some more variables from intent.getStringExtra here

        supportActionBar?.title = "$mainNote $navbarString $modeName"
    }
    // and here some methos related to this Activity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the listener to the adapter and avoid creating it and adding the logic into the adapter. Something like this:

First in the adapter class, add the listener to the constructor:

```
class ListItemCellAdpater(private val greekModeScalesList: List<ListItemTemplate>, val listener: YourListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemCellVH>()
```

then, in your viewHolder

```
class ListItemCellVH(itemCellView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemCellView) {
val note: TextView   = itemCellView.note
// defining more variables here
private val enterScaleDetailBtn: ImageButton = itemCellView.enter_scale_detail_btn

companion object {
    const val MODE_NAME : String = "MODE_NAME"
    // a bit more variable here
}


init {
    enterScaleDetailBtn.setOnClickListener{
        listener.onVHItemClicked(viewHolderModel) //or whatever info you wanted to have in the activity
    }
}
}
```

Define the interface for the listener:

```
interface YourListener(){
   fun onVHItemClicked(viewHolderModel: ViewHolderModel)
}
```

last, in your activity:

```
class MainActivity : YourListener, AppCompatActivity() {

private var listItem = ArrayList<ListItemTemplate>()

// next line we instantiate the ListItemCellAdapter from the code above
private var listItemCellAdapter = ListItemCellAdpater(listItem, this)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    reciclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    
    // next line here we set the instance to a reciclerViwe's adapter
    reciclerView.adapter = listItemCellAdapter
    
    // some listeners related to this Activity goes here
}

override fun onVHItemClicked(viewHolderModel: ViewHolderModel){
   //Here you can do the intent and add the data you need
}


// some methods related to this Activity around here}
```

Also, is not a good practice to create the adapter with the list, it's better to have a method in the adapter to update the list, then you can change the elements without creating a new adapter.

Comment: awesome. Thanks very much for the help. Two questions, though. Where should I define the interface? And, if I pass a MutableList<String> to the listener, how can I access it in the DetailView?

Comment: You can define the interface wherever you want, I usually define it in the adapter class at the very bottom.
Doesn't matter what are you passing to the listener, you'll have access in the 
override fun onVHItemClicked(viewHolderModel: ViewHolderModel){
   //Here you can do the intent and add the data you need
}
of the activity

Comment: very clear. Thanks. I'll apply everything you post to see how it works.

Comment: Hi. Now I'm being able to pass data from the MainActivity to DetailView, that's the result I wanted, I'm really thankful for that, but still there's a small detail, I still want to be able to pass all the data that it's left behind inside the ViewHolder. I hope I'm not asking too much, but could you give me a hand on that as well?

Comment: I think I don't understand the use case.
The info you are missing is in the main activity or in the view holder?
If it's in the activity you'll need to add all the info you want to send in the intent data.
If the info is in the adapter, you can modify the listener to send the info you need, objects, primitives... and then send to the details activity with the intent.

Comment: No problem then. I was able to fill that gap. I had to make use of Parcelable, and make some small changes like remove the init and listener from the ViewHolder and set the button's listener inside Adapter's onBindViewHolder method and pass the target in the parameter. Everything good now. Learned a lot. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to define a `callback` function in `MainActivity` and then pass this callback to your `ListItemCellAdpater` and `ListItemCellVH` and then simply invoke this callback when any `RecyclerView` item is clicked. this way all your logic to open `GMScaleDetailActivity` and passing data in `Intent` can be placed in `MainActivity`

In `MainActivity`

```
val itemClickHandler: () -> Unit = {
// open your detail activity with required data
}
```

Update `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` to receive this callback as

```
class ListItemCellAdpater(private val clickHandler: () -> Unit, 
                          private val greekModeScalesList: List<ListItemTemplate>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemCellVH>() {}


class ListItemCellVH(private val clickHandler: () -> Unit,
                     itemCellView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemCellView) { }
```

Now when you create ListItemCellAdapter in `MainActivity` simply pass the callback as

```
private var listItemCellAdapter = ListItemCellAdpater(itemClickHandler, listItem)
```

Comment: Hi. I tested both approaches given by you and Grala, they work as I was wanting, but also I didn't want to lose track of the data inside that ListItemCellVH class. As in my first code, there's some data being transfered through intent, and I need those data as well as the data from the MainActivity together, somehow. Is that possible to achieve? Thanks for the already given help.